# What the difference between would you like me or for me

Tags: meaning

I am not native so i dont understand if this sentence means i should have send some documents  for somebody or somebody wants to send me some documents?! 
(would you like for me to send the lists of  documents for a student and visitors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sentence:

"Would you like for me to send the lists of documents for a student and visitors."

the preposition "for" looks **unnecessary**. So if removed:

"Would you like me to send the lists of documents for a student and visitors."

It will mean that they ask you if you want them (him/ her) to send the lists of documents...

It will mean if you want that they will send it.

Comment: So without removing "for", what does it mean?

Comment: Will mean the same as without the "for." That expression, "like for," used to be strictly a southern American regionalism, but it is now spread throughout the United States. It has never been accepted outside the US and is never heard (according to Burchfield), in the UK. The "for" is certainly not necessary, but it's not wrong to use it.

Comment: Why can't I submit a new question to this Forum?? Can you please help to remove the strange ban? I am helping out others, earning points etc, Yet can't post a new question to the forum ???

Comment: What should I do??